# No overload matches this call. TypeScript error while using `next-connect` & `next-iron-session`

Tags: typescript, next.js, session-state, next-connect

I have a project using `next-connect` & `next-iron-session`.

`next-connect` by default uses `<NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>` & I'm using `<NextIronRequest, NextApiResponse>` where

```
export type AppSession = {
  session: Session
}

export type NextIronRequest = NextApiRequest & AppSession
```

But I'm unable to pass `<NextIronRequest, NextApiResponse>` to `nc` like:

```
return nc<NextIronRequest, NextApiResponse>({
    onError: (err, _, res) => {
      error(err)
      res.status(500).end(err.toString())
    },
  })
```

This should solve my issue but it gives me error:

> Expected 0 type arguments, but got 2.ts(2558)

I get the overload error on my `handler()` function like:

```
export default handler()
  .get('/twitter/generate-auth-link', generateAuthLink)
  .get('/twitter/get-verifier-token', getVerifierToken)
```

I get 2 errors on each method saying:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(...handlers: RequestHandler[]): NextConnect', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(pattern: string | RegExp, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): NextConnect', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: NextIronRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler'.
> Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
> Type 'NextApiRequest' is not assignable to type 'NextIronRequest'.
> Property 'session' is missing in type 'NextApiRequest' but required in type 'AppSession'.ts(2769)

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(...handlers: RequestHandler[]): NextConnect', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(pattern: string | RegExp, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): NextConnect', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: NextIronRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler'.
> Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
> Type 'NextApiRequest' is not assignable to type 'NextIronRequest'.
> Type 'NextApiRequest' is not assignable to type 'AppSession'.ts(2769)

How do I solve it?

My complete reproduction is here → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/twitter-api-v2-3-legged-login-using-next-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was using an old version of `next-connect`.

I had cloned the repo from `next/examples` so that must be why it was on an old version.

Upgrading `next-connect` fixed this issue.